# MIPS Assembler trouble - Arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have an assembly code containing an array, and I simply cannot understand what actually the result in the $s2 register shows. If someone could help and explain or simplify it for me that would be great.
Here's the code:

```
.data     arr:     .word     3 2 -6 1 4 10 530 115 2231 1422
          arrSize: .word 10
.text
.global   main

main:
la        $s0, arr
la        $t0, arrSize
lw        $s1, 0($t0)
add       $s2, $zero, $zero

loop:
lw        $t1, 0($s0)
andi      $t2, $t1, 1
bne       $t2, $zero, skip
addi      $s2, $s2, 1

skip:
addi      $s0, $s0, 4
addi      $s1, $s1, -1
bne       $s1, $zero, loop  

end:
add       $v0, $zero, $s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some pseudo-code comments to the code:

```
.data     arr:     .word     3 2 -6 1 4 10 530 115 2231 1422
          arrSize: .word 10
.text
.global   main

main:

    la        $s0, arr            ;; s0 = arr          // init s0 = pointer to start of arr
    la        $t0, arrSize        ;; t0 = &arr_size    // get no of elements in arr
    lw        $s1, 0($t0)         ;; s1 = arr_size = 10
    add       $s2, $zero, $zero   ;; s2 = 0            // init count of even elements = 0

    loop:                         ;; do {              // for all elements in arr do
    lw        $t1, 0($s0)         ;;    t1 = *s0       //   get element from arr
    andi      $t2, $t1, 1         ;;    t2 = t1 & 1    //   test element for odd/even-ness
    bne       $t2, $zero, skip    ;;    if (t2 != 0)   //   if not odd (i.e. even) then
    addi      $s2, $s2, 1         ;;        s2++       //     increment count in s2

skip:
    addi      $s0, $s0, 4         ;;    s0++           //   increment pointer to next element in arr
    addi      $s1, $s1, -1        ;;    s1--           //   decrement count of elements to process
    bne       $s1, $zero, loop    ;; } while (s1 != 0) // end of do loop

end:
    add       $v0, $zero, $s2     ;; v0 = s2           // return result in v0
```

It seems that this just iterates through the elements of `arr`, testing each element to see if it is even, and incrementing a count of even elements found. The final result (in `v0` and `s2`) will be 6, since there are 6 even elements in the array.

Comment: Wouldn't it count the even elements, since it jumps to `skip` if the lsb is set? (I'm assuming the assembler is filling the delay branch slots with NOPs or some such, since you don't have to take delayed branching into account with SPIM/MARS IIRC).

Comment: @Michael: yes, I think you're right - I got the logic inverted - let me fix that...

Comment: Perhaps the comment for the `addi` should be changed to `if (t2 == 0)` or `if (t2 != 0) goto skip;`

Comment: I've updated the comments to make the logic clearer - the structured equivalent is "if not odd then increment count" versus the asm implementation which is "if odd then skip, otherwise increment count".